# How can I convert monsters from D&D 3 or 3.5 to 2ed monsters?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, dnd-3e, adnd-2e, conversion

I would like to know if I can convert monsters from 3.x editions  (I already figured out how to convert monsters from the 1ed) into 2ed monsters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For 3.X monsters:

Keep the HP and HD as listed in 3E.
Assign the THAC-0 based upon the HD.
Convert spells by name; most early 3E stuff is direct from 2E.

Convert saves by feel; level should be same as HD. Combat monsters should be as fighter; spell-users as MU or Cleric. Sneaky poisoners as Thief, etc.

Assign asterisks as per the DMG guidelines.

Note: There was a conversion manual for characters from 2E to 3E. It's quite possible to work backwards with it for converting NPCs, but it's much easier to just grab the atts, and lose 1 point of stats per 4 levels, and use same class and level, assigning proficiencies by feel.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to show by example; +1.